# What completion modes am I using?

Tags: debugging, minor-mode, auto-complete-mode

I do not curate my `.emacs` and packages very effectively. Right now I have an issue where, when working in the Ruby, I type `def[space]` and then magically *two* `end` lines appear. Obviously I have managed to turn on two different autocompletion systems and they are both activating. Is it ruby-mode? rails-mode? autocomplete mode? Something else?

I'm sure I can hunt down this specific case, but my general issue is that it's hard to tell what emacs features are turned on and which are activating at any given time. There's so much stuff in my mode line that I don't know where to start.

How do you diagnose such issues? Are there tools for taming an emacs config gone wild?

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsBankruptcy

Comment: M-x `describe-mode` will show you all the currently active mode. And for taming, just start with an empty init file, and retrieve, tested piece, after tested piece, your config from the old init file.

Comment: One is probably coming from `smart-parens` or the like. Do you have another overlapping packages installed? Like `autopairs`?

Comment: I found that one is coming from `ruby-end-mode`, I'm not sure when I ever installed that. There must be another snippet package in there too.